# NullPointerException when calling method on a null Map

Tags: java, exception

Why the below code throws null pointer excetion in test.put(1,"sd")

```
public class HashMap {
  @SuppressWarnings("null")
  public static void main(String a[]){
    Map test = null;
    test.put(1, "sd");  
    System.out.println(test);
  }
}
```

Comment: This question is not related to maps.

Comment: By the way. The warning you suppressed is warning you exactly about the mistake you made.

Comment: man you need to read about Map. first do that and then try something cause i see a huge gap here

Answer (score 0):

Because test is null.

```
Map test = null;
```

Try instantiating the map instead.

```
Map test = new HashMap();
```

Or try a parameterized map:

```
Map<Integer,String> test = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
```

Comment: but then i am inserting value 
  -- test.put(1, "sd");  
Then y an exception

Comment: You can't insert a value into a null object.  The object must exist before you can add a value.

Comment: @user3839699 what, exactly, do you think you are inserting a value *into*?  You haven't created a `Map` to put your data in - you're explicitly using `null`....